# Updating database for desktop application (patching)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I wonder what you are using for updating a client database when your program is patched?

Let's take a look at this scenario:

1. You have a desktop application (.net, entity framework) which is using sql server compact database.
2. You release a new version of your application which is using extended database.
3. The user downloads a patch with modified files
4. How do you update the database?

I wonder how you are doing this process. I have some conception but I think more experienced people can give me better and tried solutions or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a **migration framework**.

There are existing OSS libraries like FluentMigrator

- [project page](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator)
- [wiki](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki)
- [long "Getting started" blogpost](http://lostechies.com/seanchambers/2011/04/02/fluentmigrator-getting-started/)

Entity Framework Code First will also get its own migration framework, but it's still in beta:

- [Code First Migrations: Beta 1 Released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/29/code-first-migrations-beta-1-released.aspx)
- [Code First Migrations: Beta 1 ‘No-Magic’ Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/29/code-first-migrations-beta-1-no-magic-walkthrough.aspx)
- [Code First Migrations: Beta 1 ‘With-Magic’ Walkthrough (Automatic Migrations)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/29/code-first-migrations-beta-1-with-magic-walkthrough-automatic-migrations.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide explicitly or hidden in your code DB upgrade mechanism, and - thus implement something like DB versioning chain

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of aspects to it.
First is versioning. You need some way of tying teh version of teeh db to the version of the program, could be something as simple as table with a version number in it. You need to check it on executing the application as well.

One fun scenario is you 'update' application and db successfully, and then for some operational reason the customer restores a previous version of the db, or if you are on a frequent patch cycle, do you have to do each patch in order or can thay catch up. Do you want to deal with application only or database only upgrades differently?

There's no one right way for this, you have to look at what sort of changes you make, and what level of complexity you are prepared to maintain in order to cope with everything that could go wrong.

A couple a of things worth looking at.
Two databases, one for static 'read-only' data, and one for more dynamic stuff. Upgrading the static data, can then simply be a restore from a resource within the upgrade package.

The other is how much can you do with meta-data, stored in db tables. For instance a version based xsd to describe your objects instead of a concrete class. That's goes in your read only db, now you've updated code and application with a restore and possibly some transforms.

Lots of ways to go, just remember
'users' will always find some way of making you look like an eejit, by doing something you never thought they would.

The more complex you make the system, the more chance of the above.

And last but not least, don't take short cuts on data version conversions, if you lose data integrity, everything else you do will be wasted.